# What is $\ E[3^X]=?$ $\ E[1/(X+1)]=?$

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Let $\ X\sim\text{Pois}(λ)$ 
1) What is $\ E[3^X]=?$
Sol: $\ E[X]=λ$ ,  $\ E[3^X ]=3^λ$
2) What is $\ E[1/(X+1)]=?$
Sol: $\ 1/(1+λ)$
**Is my sol true?**

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\mathbb E[f(x)]$?

Comment: @tia no sadly..

Comment: $E[f(X)]$ is in general going to be different than $f(E[X])$.  Take for simple example $X$ uniformly distributed over $\{-2,2\}$ and $f(X)=X^2$.  You'd notice that $E[X]=0$ here and $f(E[X])=f(0)=0^2=0$, however $f(X)$ is always $4$, so $E[f(X)]=E[4]=4$, not $0$.

Comment: As for definitions... $f(X)$ is going to be a random variable as well, so the definition of $E[f(X)]$ is just like the usual definition of expected value just with $f(X)$ as the random variable rather than the simpler $X$.  Try expressing your expected values in your question in their raw definition form using summations or integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the PMF for a poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is

$$Pr(X=k) = \frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

Now... if we were to try to find $E[X]$ here, that would correspond to the summation:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k\cdot Pr(X=k) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty k\cdot \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} = \lambda$$

Finding $E[f(X)]$ will instead be:  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty f(k)\cdot Pr(X=k)$

(*Recall that the limits on the summation are a result of this being the support of the distribution*)

So, for your exact problem being asked, you are being tasked with trying to find the following two summations:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 3^k\cdot\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$ and $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}\cdot\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$

As for hints on how to evaluate these, recall what the Taylor series expansion for $e^z$ looks like.

Comment: I think I should find  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 3^k\cdot Pr(X=3^k)$

Comment: @AssiaKhteb no.  We aren't interested in whether or not $X=3^k$, we are interested in whether or not $f(X)=3^k$.  If you insist on writing it that way you could do so as $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 3^k\cdot Pr(3^X=3^k)$.  I chose not to write it this way because although going from $3^X=3^k$ to $X=k$ is relatively easy to do, this is not so easy for other functions and is flat out wrong for some such as going from $X^2=k^2$ to $X=k$.  It is far easier to deal with the support of $X$ rather than the support of $f(X)$.

Comment: In this special case, you can recognize that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 3^k Pr(3^X=3^k)$ is exactly the same as writing $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 3^k Pr(X=k)$

Comment: Thank you so much for helping @JMoravitz